# How can I show the last few months of commits in the contribution graph?

Tags: github

I will fixed the problem is commit count not showing on Contribution graph but still a single problem is how can I show the last few months of commits in the contribution graph in GitHub?
So if anyone knows the solution to this problem, please help me.